# React Native Header Right Icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue with my header right icon. I would like my right icon on the header bar be a search icon and I get the title name of the icon instead. [my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRQ0Y.png)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

I followed the tutorial : https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-header-buttons and please find the part of my code that should render the icon.

```js
ProductsOverviewScreen.navigationOptions={
    headerTitle: 'All products',
    headerRight : <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonCompoenent = {HeaderButton}>
        <Item title='Cart' iconName={'ios-search'} onPress={()=>{}}/>
    </HeaderButtons>
}
```

Here is the full page code if needed :

```js
//LIST OF ALL PRODUCTS WE CAN ORDER
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native'
//useStore -- helps use to go into the redux store and get our products from there
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'

import ProductItem from '../../components/shop/ProductItem'

//importing all cart actions
import * as cartActions from '../../store/actions/cart'

import {HeaderButtons, Item} from 'react-navigation-header-buttons'
import HeaderButton from '../../components/UI/HeaderButton'

//This is a component named ProductsOverviewScreen
const ProductsOverviewScreen = props => {
    //products : placed in the combine reducers function in App.js
    //here we get all the available products using useSelector which gets as input the state and we can retrieve the data from there
    // ---- allows you to extract data from the Redux store state
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products.availableProducts)
    //Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store. They are the only source of information for the store. 
    //You send them to the store using store.dispatch()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList 
                data={products} 
                keyExtractor={item=> item.id} 
                renderItem={
                    itemData => <ProductItem 
                                            image={itemData.item.imageUrl} 
                                            title={itemData.item.title} 
                                            price={itemData.item.price}
                                            //props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail') will take us to the ProductDetail screen 
                                            //{productId: itemData.item.id} pass productId to the ProductDetail screen
                                            onViewDetail = {() => {props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail', {
                                                productId: itemData.item.id,
                                            })}}
                                            onAddToCart = {() => {
                                                dispatch(cartActions.addToCart(itemData.item))
                                            }}
                                        />}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

ProductsOverviewScreen.navigationOptions={
    headerTitle: 'All products',
    headerRight : <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonCompoenent = {HeaderButton}>
        <Item title='Cart' iconName={'ios-search'} onPress={()=>{}}/>
    </HeaderButtons>
}

//export so that the component is available elsewhere
export default ProductsOverviewScreen
```

Comment: Can u share your page's full code please?

Comment: I just added it in my question :)

Comment: Dİd u import  'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons' to HeaderButton component ?

Comment: I have the following import for my icons. Isn't it enough ? import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons'    What is the difference between the two imports ?

Comment: Did u try to add import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'; to this page above react-navigation-header-buttons import

Comment: Yes I did and there is no change... It is still the same as before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this HeaderButtonCompoenent is misspelled try to change and add ( )around your headerbuttons.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a silly mistake, try adding `()` around the `headerRight` component.

```js
ProductsOverviewScreen.navigationOptions={
    headerTitle: 'All products',
    headerRight : (
      <HeaderButtons headerButtonCompoenent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item title='Cart' iconName={'ios-search'} onPress={()=>{}}/>
    </HeaderButtons>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I still get the same problem...

Comment: Edited my answer, there was a spelling mistake. Can you try now?